# How to click on href="javascript:void(0)" link and pass path to opened window (Selenium)

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-firefoxdriver

On the page there is a element like this:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)"> Computer durchsuchen </a>
```

If you click on this link a window opens in which you can select an image (the path). I managed to click on the link and the window opens. My question is now how can I pass the path and how can I close it again?

[This is the site it concerns...](https://www.shirtee.com/de/designer/?id=1140/)

This is the code I've made work so far:

```
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

    driver.get("https://www.shirtee.com/de/designer/?id=1140/");
    WebElement link = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".upload-image-drop-zone a"));

    Actions ob = new Actions(driver);
    ob.click(link);
    org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Action action  = ob.build();
    action.perform();
```

[Here you can see a screenshot of the processes that happen...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZYVJJ.png)

Answer (score 0):

Since `Selenium` cannot interact with native windows, you can use a `Robot` class for it:

```
Robot robot = new Robot();
StringSelection selection = new StringSelection("Absolute path of the file");
Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().setContents(selection,null);

robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_V);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_V);
robot.setAutoDelay(2000);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
```

The full code would be like this:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.datatransfer.StringSelection;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

public class Test  {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, AWTException {
    final WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

    driver.get("https://www.shirtee.com/de/designer/?id=1140/");

    WebElement link = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".upload-image-drop-zone a"));
    link.click();
    Thread.sleep(500); // small pause

    Robot robot = new Robot();
    StringSelection selection = new StringSelection("C:\\full\\path\\to\\file\\image.png");
    Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().setContents(selection,null);

    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_V);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_V);
    robot.setAutoDelay(2000);
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);

    Thread.sleep(3000); // only to see the result
    driver.quit();
  }
}
```

More information you can find in the documentation [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html).